# Inifinite Scroll Recycleview's imageview flickering when scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging

I'm showing images from server with Google Paging Library. When I show images from Localhost, it work perfect but with live server it's image is flickering. I tried to sleep Localhost for 2s to delay response but localhost's images were not flickering. My problem is same as [image-flickering-while-scrolling-in-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632056/image-flickering-while-scrolling-in-recyclerview) question. But i'm not using asynctask so can't use it's answer.

Recyclerview Adapter.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Item, ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
private Context mCtx;

ItemAdapter( Context mCtx) {
    super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_users, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}
private static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item> DIFF_CALLBACK =
        new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(Item oldItem, Item newItem) {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(Item oldItem, Item newItem) {
                return oldItem.equals(newItem);
            }
        };
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Item item = getItem(position);
    final ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
    holder.image_date.setText(item.getDate());


    GlideApp
            .with(mCtx)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(item.getThumb())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder.imageview);
}


class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView image_date, image_weight, imageHit;
    ImageView imageView, imageView2;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    ItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        image_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_date);
        image_weight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_weight);
        imageHit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hit);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_image);
       imageView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_image2);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarThumb);
    }
}
}
```

I'm using this method. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paging-library-tutorial.
When i use same code as this method. IT work fine. Problem happen when i changed code as my use.
P.S.- Problem is when data is loading. Once data is loaded, it works fine.

Comment: Can you please add recyclerAdapter code and code to update values in recyclerview

Comment: @JinsonPaul edited the que.

Comment: Instead of glide use this code and try again                                Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50) // Your preferred size
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)

Comment: @JinsonPaul I'm  stuck at this problem for past 3 month. tried many solution. Was using onscroll for infinite sroll. Moved to paging library, thinking it will solve the issue. Don't knew that main culprit was Glide.

Comment: Does it working now

Comment: @JinsonPaul for now, it's working. Post it as answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Picasso instead of Glide .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of glide use this code and try again

```
  Picasso.with(context) .load(url) .resize(50, 50) // Your preferred size 
  .centerCrop() 
  .into(imageView);
```